# safeSearchDetection not finding image

Tags: node.js, firebase, types, google-cloud-functions

I've been stuck on this problem for the past 36 hours. I'm going through the Codelabs tutorial for Firebase Cloud Functions.
My app is already deployed to firebase hosting.

When I send my image file from the root:

```
gs://sistema-ximbo.appspot.com
```

My function works perfectly, but when I send the file into the images directory. it does not work, how do I specify a directory?

```
gs://sistema-ximbo.appspot.com/imagens
```

IMPORTS ****

export const tesla369 = functions.storage

```
.bucket(bucketName)
.object()
.onChange( async event => {
        const object = event.data;
        const filePath = object.name;
        const imageUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${filePath}`;
        const docId = filePath.split('.jpg')[0];
        const docRef  = admin.firestore().collection('photos').doc(docId);
        // Text Extraction
        const textRequest = await visionClient.documentTextDetection(imageUri)
        const fullText = textRequest[0].textAnnotations[0]
        const text =  fullText ? fullText.description : null
        // Web Detection
        const webRequest = await visionClient.webDetection(imageUri)
        const web = webRequest[0].webDetection
        // Faces
        const facesRequest = await visionClient.faceDetection(imageUri)
        const faces = facesRequest[0].faceAnnotations
        // Landmarks
        const landmarksRequest = await visionClient.landmarkDetection(imageUri)
        const landmarks = landmarksRequest[0].landmarkAnnotations

        // Save to Firestore
        const data = { text, web, faces, landmarks }
        return docRef.set(data)
```

});

```
 const imageUri = `gs://${bucketName}/'imagens'/${filePath}`;



I've tried it in every possible way, but it only works when I send the image to the root, if I send into the images folder, the function of this error:
```

tesla369

```
 Error: Argument "documentPath" must point to a document, but was "imagens/pagina1". Your path does not contain an even number of components.
```